# Hexo pagination on custom page

Tags: hexo

According to Hexo [docs](https://hexo.io/docs/variables.html), only the index and archive pages have access to `page.prev_link` and `page.next_link`. Is there some way we can configure a custom page to also gain access to these variables so we can do pagination?

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure out how to add pagination variables to *any* page but I was able to rename the archive page to something else. For example, let's say you want a page called /blog, just change this in `config.yml`:

`archive_dir: blog`

Now the URL will be `/blog` instead of `/archive`. Of course this means you will no longer have an archive page.

Comment: you probably also need `permalink: blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/`, so url of a post becomes example.com/blog/2001/03/21/a-post, assuming `root: /`.